# Taking a MySQL snapshot and recreating the database?

Tags: mysql, backup, snapshot

If a snapshot of the database is taken, can it be copied over to another drive and re-created?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you mean creating a dump and restoring it, or do you mean moving the actual location of the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "copied over to another drive", but a very good tool to create a snapshot of a running database is [`mysqlhotcopy`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html)

> mysqlhotcopy is a Perl script that was originally written and contributed by Tim Bunce. It uses FLUSH TABLES, LOCK TABLES, and cp or scp to make a database backup. It is a fast way to make a backup of the database or single tables, but it can be run only on the same machine where the database directories are located.